# "Is there a" vs "is there any"?

Tags: word-choice

Which one of these is right?

> Is there a way [...]?

> Is there any way [...]?

May I use either? If yes, what's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The expression *a way* alludes to one particular way. The expression *any way* alludes to one of any number of possible ways.

As you mentioned in your astute comment, at the time of asking the question, there's really no difference. Yes, you can use either one of them – in this context.

Consider:

> Is there **a way** to roll babookamitzes uphill, without breaking into a sweat?
> Is there **any way** to roll babookamitzes uphill, without breaking into a sweat?

I would say that these questions have **no difference in meaning**. Why? Let's assume I know three ways to accomplish this task. No matter which question you asked me, my answer would be the same:

> Yes, I know at least three ways to do that.

I would not be more or less inclined to mention only one method if you used *a way* instead of *any way*, or vice-versa.

In other contexts, though, the words *a* and *any* are not interchangeable. In fact, in some contexts, replacing one with the other would result in an ungrammatical statement:

> I know **a** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople. `okay`
> I know **any** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople. `incorrect`
>
> **Any** time we try to plan a picnic, it rains. `okay`
> **A** time we try to plan a picnic, it rains. `incorrect`

But, in the context of **asking a question about solving a problem**, either one is just fine:

> Do you know **a** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople?
> Do you know **any** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople?
> <sub>(answer to both questions: *Yes: we can fly, or take a train*.)</sub>

Comment: I just can say Great!

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful, but I always feel a little funny seeing an answer accepted so quickly (in this case, 10 minutes). I'd rather wait 10 hours. I've always thought it's best to wait awhile; after all, there may be something I'm forgetting here, or someone could compose an even better answer. You might want to visit [this interesting discussion](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/648), and keep those thoughts in mind for next time.

Comment: For sure. Again really useful. Indeed I thought you mentioned exactly what I wanted, but you are true.

Comment: Does the distinction between *a* and *any* arise because, in those cases, *a* is being used as a synonym for *some* instead? e.g. I know *some* way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople.

Comment: @J.R., "Do you know **a** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople" sounds wrong, as compared to "Do you know **any** way we can get to Timbuktu from Constantinople"

Comment: @Pacerier - Actually, I think they both sound a bit contrived, but that's the wording the O.P. asked about. Personally, I'd be inclined to say something more like, "How can we get from Timbuktu to Constantinople? Any ideas?"

Answer (score 12):

I have to partially <strike>disagree with</strike> *extend* J.R.'s answer here. They are correct that when asking the question

> Is there any/a way to...

it is often the case that the two words are interchangeable. However, this is only the case when there's a neutral tone to the question. For instance, the question

> Is there a way to draw a perfect circle?

works just as well as

> Is there any way to draw a perfect circle?

*But* if the question has an implicit extra meaning, then this is no longer the case. For instance, after spending several hours trying to draw a perfect circle, one might yell

> Is there **any** way to draw a perfect circle?

In which case `any` cannot simply be replaced with `a`, as it would remove the speaker's implicit suggestion that no such method appears to exist. Not to mention that emphasizing `a` comes off as an awkward speech pattern here. By shifting the emphasis, one could get the sentence

> **Is** there a way to draw a perfect circle?

Which is very *similar*, but has, to my mind, a slightly different tone.

Similarly, if your neighbour is blasting music, one may ask

> Is there any way you could turn down the music?

Which does not work as well with `a`, because `any` suggests an uncertainty. In this case this is done to make the phrase more polite. You are requesting that the volume be lowered, but allowing for the possibility that the volume has a good reason to be high.

In summary, I would say that using `a` usually expresses a lack of assumptions about the answer to the question, while using `any` *can* suggest that one doubts or is uncertain of the existence of a solution.

Edit: If in doubt, I would favour always using `any` over `a` in a question like this, as I am at a loss for any context in which `a` could not reasonably be replaced with `any`.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you are _disagreeing_ with my previous answer, so much as _making it more complete_. Nice analysis. +1.

Comment: @J.R. fair enough. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @J.R., Your answer stated that they are equal. And he's disagreeing that they are equal.

Comment: @Pacerier - Alexis left an answer about a context that I hadn't considered. I think we both agree with each others' answers.

Answer (score 7):

I think J.R. and Alexis are correct, although I would add that when asking a question in this manner "any" often adds a nuance that the speaker expects that the answer will be "no" or something negative.

For these examples:

- A: Is there a way to roll babookamitzes uphill, without breaking into a sweat?
- B: Is there any way to roll babookamitzes uphill, without breaking into a sweat?

"A" sounds neutral, however "B" has a more negative nuance implying that the speaker thinks that answer is no.

Comment: Either thinks the answer is no, or else is getting exasperated or frustrated, perhaps. You're right, though, sometimes there are slight nuances, even if the underlying meaning is fairly consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct!

> Is there a way? - You are a bit specific about **that** way (though you don't know). 
>   Is there [any](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=any) way? - You are talking about some way without any specification.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I think in both cases I don't know that even if there is a way, so how can I be specific. I'll be really thankful if you explain more.

Comment: Check this about *any*, this'll clarify the matter - http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/any

Comment: @mok Okay, let me try but not in this case. If you need some money, you ask to your colleague *Is there a person who can help me?* This would directly mean can someone (there in your group/office/acquaintance) help you? If you say, is there *anyone* who can help me, it becomes broader and includes *any* person on this earth!

Comment: @MaulikV, In your above quote, shouldn't "a person" be replaced by "someone"?

Comment: someone is *again* specific though unknown. Say--there's 'someone' in the kitchen. @Pacerier