# Some people don't have an/any option

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Do both the following sentences mean the same?

1- Some people don't have any option except to use public transportation.

2- Some people don't have an option except to use public transportation.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. Here "**an**" may or may not convey the idea of "**any**":

- Some people don't [have any option except](https://www.google.ru/search?biw=1536&bih=779&q=%22have%20any%20option%20except%22&oq=%22have%20any%20option%20except%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3556.3556.0.3922.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.egOS6GksKQ8) to use public transportation.
- Some people don't [have an option except](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22have%20an%20option%20except%22&oq=%22have%20an%20option%20except%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.152j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to use public transportation.

"**any**" here means that there aren't one or more possible options while "**an**" means that there isn't a single possible option.

Meanwhile in the affirmative sentence the meaning will be different.

- Is there **any** option other than to use public transportation. *(Means that there can be one or more than one option)*
- Is there **an** option other than to use public transportation. *(Means that there can be only one option)*

This question [**“Is there a” vs “is there any”**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18293/is-there-a-vs-is-there-any) and J.R. answer might help you.